# read connectionstring from WebConfig file in dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a `class library project(dll)` and an `MVC` project(I'm using `ASP.net Core` with `.net`framework). How can I read the `connectionstring` that is inside the `WebConfig` file of my MVC project in the `dll`? I'm inside the `dll` and I need to read it, I don't want to put the `connectionstring` hardcoded in there too if I have it already inside the WebConfig of the MVC project, how could I do that?
I'm using in my dll this code but it's not working:

```
   var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: `but it's not working` <= please be more specific. Do you have an exception? Did you check the spelling? Is `null` being returned? What is happening. Finally see this article on connection strings in asp.net core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings

Comment: @Igor I'm getting a `An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ProjectClasses.dll but was not handled in user code`

Comment: That most likely means that `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionStringName"]` is returning `null` but you need to verify that. So I would check the content of the `web.config` and make sure the spelling/casing are the same of the connection string name. If it is then post the content in your question.

Comment: @Igor I've checked the names and are exactly the same, the same code is working in a pure MVC project, maybe I need to do something else considering that is an ASP.net Core project even if is very similar to MVC, or maybe I would need to pass it as an argument as the response suggest

Comment: Passing in a connection string to your database context class's instantiation is a fairly typical pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the connection string in as an argument when you use / instantiate your class from the class library rather than attempting to access web.config directly from the class library. This is a fairly common practice and will be more recognizable to other people who may need to maintain your code.

```
//in the MVC code somewhere
string conStr = null;
if(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionStringName"] != null)
   conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
else
{
   //connection string not found
}
//instantiating class from the class library
var myFoo = new Foo(conStr);
```